# User preference matching recommendation system ( pearson correlation )

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I will point this out first, my knowledge of algorithms is very modest and am working on improving this with the recommendation system I am working on ( this is for my own educational gain ).

### Background

So far, I have a list of user preferences to work into a correlation with other user preferences.  Each users will have the following data:

- Major:  ( Business, Computer Science, Nursing, ect ... )
- Gender: ( Male, Female )
- Age: ( numeric value )
- Ethnicity: ( American Indian/Alaskan Native, Black/African American, Hispanic/Latino, Asian/Pacific Islander, White, Not of Hispanic Origin )

My goal is to rank the persons that are participating with each other.  So, User1 would have a list of ranked users like so:

1. User4 - 89%
2. User20 - 34%
3. User234 - 31%

Right now, I can do the ranking if I give each of the users preference a rating ( 1 - 5 ). Then use the Pearson Coefficient to rank them. The user class has a mapping like this:

User1: ( name, rank )

- Major -> computer science, 3
- Gender -> male, 5
- Age -> 18, 5
- Ethnicity -> white, 3

I found this link and appears to be close to what I want to do: [User matching with current data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574929/user-matching-with-current-data)

### Questions

- Am I using the right algorithm for this process?
- How can I take something like 'Computer Science' and give it a value to use with the Pearson Coefficient?
- Can I generate the 'rank' on the fly? ( How can I do this? )

The programming language I am using is C#.  Also, if possible, I would like to do this without the aid of a library as the goal is to learn more advanced CS topics.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to construct is a feature vector. Let me illustrate one way to do this. Note this is not the only way to do this.

You have categorical variables. (atleast most of them).

Every feature which is valid for a user .. indicate it as 1 otherwise 0

So lets say you feature vector is indicated by

```
[Business, Computer Science, Nursing, Male, Female , American Indian/Alaskan Native, African American, Hispanic/Latino, Asian/Pacific Islander, White, Not of Hispanic Origin ]
```

Note that I have ignored age here as age is a numeric feature and not a categorical one.

One way to solve that out is , discretize your age variable.. i.e represent age as 0-10,10-20..and so on..
And this way you can indicate these buckets into the equation.

Now image you have a user who is comp sci major, male american indian
This can be indicated as:

```
[0,1,0,1,0, 1 .......]
```

Indicate all of your users in this form...

After you have indicated all the users in this form (feature vectors), you can take dot product (cosine similarity)or use any similarity measure to achieve your purpose.
Higher the similarity score, more similar the user is. and you can use this score to rank the users.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The numerical bucket is where I got stuck.  Your idea makes sense and I believe I was over complicating the matter.  I should finish this project :p

Comment: though age can also be treated as categorical variable (assuming you have age in integer years) but i am guessing that this will render you a very sparse feature vector as then you will have fields like [... age_1, age_2,age_3,age_4...age_100... ] and since just one of this will be "1" and rest "0", this will render your feature vector very sparse.. discreticizing this will give you not so sparse representation.